# force load from server instead of cache on session start

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I ensure that the user has the latest .js file cached in his browser? I'd like to have the app force the browser to a complete reload of all files on every session start.

Let me know how this can be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would use an extra cache buster parameter on your < script > tag:

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="my-script.js?v=1" / >
```

Then every time you make a change to my-script.js, you can increase the version number:

```
src="my-script.js?v=2"
src="my-script.js?v=3"
src="my-script.js?v=4"
src="my-script.js?v=5"
```

And so on.. now when the user comes back, their browser will be forced to download the updated javascript.

Comment: ok that's a good solution that works. Anything in the .net framework that does the job?